# Remove Libraries from Windows 10 Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry, windows-libraries

How do I remove Libraries from Windows Explorer in Windows 10?

- Pressing delete while the registry folder is selected does nothing.
- Right-clicking to get the context menu does not reveal a delete option.
- The Navigation pane option for libraries is already disabled.
- This is obviously a registry issue.
- Clean/full install of Windows 10 Build 18363.

[image: Broken GUI Libraries]

[image: Windows Explorer Libraries]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## wenpcfg

### (Windows Explorer Navigation Pane Configuration)

This works in Windows 10 21H1 and Widows 7:

Step 1: Download :

https://github.com/andif888/wenpcfg

Step 2: Create a `batch.bat` file with the following contents (choose your options):

```
wenpcfg /HideLibraries

wenpcfg /HideFavorites

wenpcfg /HideHomeGroup
```

Step 3: Run `batch.bat`.

Step 4: Log out of the Windows user account and log back in.

Answer (score 2):

**Update** - Doesn't work on Win10 (20H2 and later) and Win11

---

For older Win10 systems, try the tutorial at [TenForums](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4222-hide-show-libraries-navigation-pane-windows-10-a.html) - Option 2 and Option 4

**Option 2**:

Open File Explorer, click on `File`, select `Options`

[image: File Explorer Options]

Click on `View` tab, scroll down and uncheck `Show libraries` and click/tap on `OK`.

[image: Option to show libraries in file explorer]

**Option 4**:

- Run `regedit`
- Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{031E4825-7B94-4dc3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}`
- Create new DWORD by right clicking > New > DWORD (32-bit Value) > `System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree` if it doesn't already exist
- Set value of DWORD to`0` (by double clicking on DWORD or right click > Modify) to hide Libraries

Answer (score 1):

This solution will completely remove Library folder from Explorer navigation bar, not just close it:

[Windows 7: Libraries Folder - Add or Remove from Navigation Pane](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/35627-libraries-folder-add-remove-navigation-pane.html)

Only thing which differs from Windows 7 is that **ShellFolder** key is owned by the owner "SYSTEM" and it will prevent you from changing values!
To overcome this, in step **5** you should **first click** to the "Advanced" button, then in new dialog change owner "SYSTEM" to "Administrators":

[image]

and then apply **Full Control access** and proceed with other actions in the step 5 and later.

*This is checked on Windows 10 Pro, version 1607, build 14393.0 and version 1909, build 18363.418*

Answer (score 1):

To locate the regisry entry corresponding to a `Navigation Pane` iten, you can use this **PowerShell** to reveal the `CLSID`. Just modify the `$SerchText` value as needed:

```
$SearchText = 'Libraries'
$shell = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
@($shell.NameSpace(0).Items() | ? Name -match $SearchText).Path
```

Sample output:

```
PS C:\>@($shell.Namespace(0).Items() | ? name -match Libraries).Path

::{031E4825-7B94-4DC3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}

PS C:\>
```

Comment: replace: $shell.NameSpace(0).Items to $shell.NameSpace(0).Items()

Comment: There are not only GUID paths, it's array, it's items search so: $shell.NameSpace(0).Items() | ? Name -match $SearchText | ? Path -match '(?im)^(::{)[{(]?[0-9A-F]{8}[-]?(?:[0-9A-F]{4}[-]?){3}[0-9A-F]{12}[)}]?(})$' | Select Path

Comment: Even more:: ? Name -eq $SearchText , so: $shell.NameSpace(0).Items() | ? Name -eq $SearchText | ? Path -match '(?im)^(::{)[{(]?[0-9A-F]{8}[-]?(?:[0-9A-F]{4}[-]?){3}[0-9A-F]{12}[)}]?(})$' | Select Path

Comment: @Garric: Thanks for alerting me to the syntax error. Looks to be one of my earlier answers here. Looks like it's only intended /assumed search text would be display name of a namespace entry. Will update when I'm st a computer..