# How to remove Creative Cloud Files shortcut from Windows Explorer (left Navigation Pane) after April 2021 update?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, shortcuts, directory-listing

The "Creative Cloud Files" shortcut was a pain to get rid of in the past, but after a recent update in spring 2021, the damn shortcut is back, and none of the old tricks work anymore.

Has anybody found a method to remove it?

[image: screenshot - creative cloud files in windows explorer]

Comment: "...none of the old tricks work ...". A re you saying it's there without being added to the Shell namespace?

Comment: I'm saying that if you google "how to remove creative cloud shortcut from windows 10 explorer", none of the existing solutions work.

Comment: Try the code I posted in this answer & see what it returns. https://superuser.com/a/1633675/881098

Answer (score 21):

According to [Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/remove-cc-files-folder-shortcut-navigation-panel.html), set the following REGKEY to 1 will unpin Creative Cloud Files:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Adobe\CreativeCloud]
"unPinCCF"=dword:00000001
```

However it doesn't seem to work. This is what works for me on Windows 10 and Windows 11:

1. Open Registry Editor
2. Navigate **Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID**
3. Search for "System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree", and locate a key that contain a string **Creative Cloud Files**.
   [image]
4. Set the value of **System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree** to 0
5. Restart **Windows Explorer** for the change to take effect

Comment: I found and did all the parts in your 1-5 solution and yet, in Windows Explorer right at the top the Creative Cloud Files folder remains. (And not only did I try restart Explorer, I also restarted the whole computer.) Argh Adobe.

Comment: I could no longer find the key in RegEx. The only way now is to use the Adobe unpin tool https://helpx.adobe.com/ie/creative-cloud/kb/remove-cc-files-folder-shortcut-navigation-panel.html

Comment: @Clinton the **Adobe\CreativeCloud** key does not exist in the first place - you need to create it. However that never worked for me. Only setting **System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree** does.

Answer (score 6):

For me I had to remove this registry key:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\0E270DAA-1BE6-48F2-AC49-5CE0DBECC398`

The last part of the number is random, so open Regedit and browse to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace`, find a key starting with `0E270DAA-1BE6-48F2-AC49` and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying all the methods that I found. Nothing works for me.
I did something different, explained as follows:

1. Open "File Explorer Options" from Control Panel or the Search bar.
2. Click on View.
3. Click on "Reset Folders"
4. Then click on "Restore Default".
5. Click on "Apply".
6. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The RegEx approach described in the procedure above or described in other posts would not work for me. I expect Adobe has made a change to their implementation.

This answer gives a tested method for anyone who wants to remove the "Creative Cloud Files" shortcut, using procedure similar to that provided by Adobe.

1. Go to the Adobe help site [Adobe Unlink Tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/ie/creative-cloud/kb/remove-cc-files-folder-shortcut-navigation-panel.html).
2. Download PinCCF.zip from Adobe and extract its content.
3. There are 2 files, one for creating the link and the other for removing it.
4. Double-click on **unPinCCF.reg** (the unlink file) from the extracted folder to run it.
5. A message appears advising that you want to add unPinCCF.reg to the registry. Click Yes.
6. A confirmation message appears once the registry is successfully updated. Click OK.

You may need to restart File Explorer or Windows for the change to take effect. I did not need to do this and the "Creative Cloud Files" shortcut was immediately removed. I am using Windows 11 version 22H2.

If you later want to re-create the shortcut, all you need to do is run the rePinCCF.reg file also provided in the Adobe download zip file.

I hope this helps unclutter File Explorer a little for anyone who is not using "Creative Cloud Files".

Comment: Their tool just sets a registry key. Also it works only if you sign out of adobe cloud and sign back in.