# Adobe (Creative Cloud) Removal and RegEdit

Tags: uninstall

In a recent effort to completely remove all traces of Adobe software and Creative Cloud, following a variety of guides (I can link below). I think the absolute last breadcrumb on the trail was a (Windows 11) registry entry related to Creative Cloud which pinned it to the Local Drive Index in Windows Explorer.

[image]

I changed the value of System.IsPinnedTo... to 0 which removed it from the Local Drive Shortcuts in Explorer.

My question is can I just delete these Registry entries entirely?

Thanks for your help.

FYI: These are the guides I followed in the Adobe (Creative Cloud) removal process:
https://photographylife.com/how-to-remove-adobe-creative-cloud

Adobe has a proprietary piece of software intended to solve this problem and edit the registry but it didn't work for me.
https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/remove-cc-files-folder-shortcut-navigation-panel.html

So I did it manually
https://www.alphr.com/remove-creative-cloud-files-file-explorer-sidebar/

Comment: They make a cleaner tool - https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/cc-cleaner-tool-installation-problems.html to tidy up once you've removed all the apps - https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/help/uninstall-remove-app.html

Comment: In addition to the above, a straightforward uninstall generally works. Do not use the Registry to do this. I Install Acrobat Pro then I have to uninstall Creative Cloud (Adobe issue) and months later no Creative Cloud issues.

Comment: Thanks both. Tetsujin yes I used that tool thank you. It's detailed in the guide I linked, and also a necessary step to remove everything, but there are still quite a few items left behind which it doesn't remove, perhaps most notably the AdobeGCInvoker genuine software startup process. Re Creative Cloud drive links, Adobe offers yet another proprietary uninstall tool designed to edit the registry entry - which I linked, unpinCCF.reg -  which the CC cleaner tool doesn't remove - but that tool didn't work for me so I had to do it manually in the registry. Thanks again all.

Comment: TBH I think a clean install of the OS would have probably been simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registry entry for `{0E270DAA-1BE6-48F2-AC49-FD8E73FEA996}`
is related to Adobe and can be deleted, according to the post
[How do I remove the 'Creative Cloud Files' folder from my PC?](https://community.adobe.com/t5/creative-cloud-services-discussions/locked-how-do-i-remove-the-creative-cloud-files-folder-from-my-pc/td-p/7293612)

However, if your case is similar to the one described in this post,
and this registry entry will be re-created on the next reboot,
you will need to use the same solution of taking ownership
and setting all permissions to Deny.

In the future, I suggest using
[Revo Uninstaller Free](https://www.revouninstaller.com/products/revo-uninstaller-free/)
to uninstall software and detect all its leftovers.

Comment: Cheers! That's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can delete this registry entries.

It can be difficult to do so: For me the solution was in a comment by user [bortao](https://superuser.com/users/30489/bortao), in response to [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1642874/how-to-remove-creative-cloud-files-shortcut-from-windows-explorer-left-navigati)

I had to delete this registry key:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\0E270DAA-1BE6-48F2-AC49-5CE0DBECC398**

Bortao notes that part of the string is random. Like others, in regedit I searched on "creative cloud files" (there are a few before you hit the right one.)

Most of the support articles I found also recommended just setting the value of **System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree** from 1 to 0.  But those didn't work for me; neither did Adobe's unPinCCF tool.  But user [Aubrey](https://superuser.com/users/1673853/aubrey)'s links from the question here got me there eventually, so thanks to both of you for the help!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).